# Mi llamada de hook de estado no funciona React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

Estoy intentanto hacer un inicio de sesion con roles (admin,profesor,etc.) con Private route  pero mi hook esta arrojando null (Valor inicial) y no se esta actualizando, entonces no puedo entrar a la siguiente pagina por que necesito tener el rol en el hook

Mi **AuthProvider.js**

```
    export default function AuthProvider({children}) {
        
        const [user, setUser] = useState(null);   //Se inicializa el estado del usuario en null
        const login = (role) => setUser(role);  //Se setea el usuario con su rol 
        const logout = () => setUser(null);  //El estado del usuario se vuelve null cuando se hace logout
  
        const contextValue ={
            user,
            login,
            logout,
        };
    
        return (
            <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValue}>
                {children}
            </AuthContext.Provider>  
        )
```

Lo primero que hago es hacer la peticion http a la base datos en el componente **Login.js**

```
    export default function Login() {

      const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
      const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
      const {login} = UseAuth();
    
      async function loginUser(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/login", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            email: email,
            password: password,
          }),
        });
    
        const data = await response.json();
        const values = Object.values(data); //Obteniendo los valores de la respuesta
        const roleUser = values[2]; //Guardo el rol del usuario
        
        if (data.user) { //Si existe el usuario, inicia sesion
          
          login(roleUser);  //Llamo a la funcion login y traspaso el rol del usuario
          alert("Usuario logeado");
 
          switch (roleUser) {
            Dependiendo del rol, va a su pagina correspondiente...
          }
          
        } else {
          alert("El usuario no existe, por favor revisa tu correo y contraseña");
        }


     }
       return(Diseño componente...)
 }
```

`login(roleUser);` Aca es cuando paso el rol a la funcion login y esta deberia hacer el cambio en el AuthProvider

pero ya al momento de entrar a la ruta en:

```
switch (roleUser) {
            Dependiendo del rol, va a su pagina correspondiente...
 }
```

**`user`** sigue siento null
¿Cual deberia ser la manera de llamar al hook y que se actualice **`user`**?, Si inicializo **`user`** con algun valor, este valor siempre se mantiene, pero ya que lo inicio en `null` siempre me aparece en `null`

Comment: ¿Cuál es la función login? ¿Debería afectar en algo a roleUser? Si tienes una función login llama tu componente de otra manera para que no entre en conflicto. Y por otro lado, ¿has revisado el contenido de values? ¿Puedes poner el contenido de data/values?

Comment: Estuve investigando y necesito hacer llamado al hook en el formulario de Login.js tipo:
 <form onSubmit={login(lroleUser)}>... pero hago llamado a la funcion loginUser() en el form, la cual hace la peticion y retorna los datos del usuario y finalmente hace el login(roleUser) lo cual es invalido, como puedo hacerlo de la manera correcta? ya que tengo que buscar los datos del usuario y luego llamar al hook